# Chopin Etude How to play C-flat

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I posted a question "**Chopin Etude How to play C-flat**". It was marked as duplicate with a standard signage "This question has been asked before and already has an answer...*edit this question* to explain how it is different..(my emphasis). So I did just that. Then Dom rolled back my edit with the message *Don't try and explain why your question should be reopened in your question.* ***Take it to the meta***. I ask for anyone who is NOT Dom to look at the reason because it's blindingly obvious that mine is a new question.

Comment: I cannot see why this isn't a dupe. I agree with Dom, Jacob Swanson, Neil Meyer, Bradd Szonye and jadarne here.

Comment: There is nothing special about Chopin or etudes that changes what a C flat is, so that's not relevant to whether the question is a dupe.  The question is about enharmonic equivalence, and the core issue is exactly the same regardless of whether you ask about Cb, B#, G###, etc.

Comment: I don't know why this has several down votes. Discussing your questions closing on the meta is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @NeilMeyer metal votes are more for agreeing or disagreeing with a post. So in this case people are disagreeing.

Comment: aah OK I misuderstood.

Comment: @Dom But that's a bad concept on people raising their issue on meta (my own experience). IMHO there's no need to downvote this meta question. It would be much better to simply just upvote your answer below, or upvote the comments here you agree with the most.

Answer (score 4):

First of thanks for taking this to the meta so we can discuss this in detail.

Let's start off with why I and others closed it as a duplicate. Here's the whole question:

> Chopin Etude Op. 9 No. 2 In the 13th full bar, Right hand 5th note. My
>   music sheet shows a Cb. **What, I puzzle, is a C-flat?** Should it be
>   there? Should it be played as B natural followed by B-flat?

The bolded part is the core question. We talk about this concept which is called enharmonic equivalence a lot on this site and this is one example of it.

The B# question asks the exact same concept on a different note which is why I voted to close as a duplicate and if you look at the answers for your question and the other question, you'll see they are extremely similar in nature with the only difference being the exact note.

This was your edit that you made to your post:

> *I disagree that this question duplicates the question* What does this note - B# - mean? *which concerns a different note in a different key
>   played on an unspecified instrument not necessarily a piano, and
>   probably not composed by Chopin.*

The key is different yes, the note is different yes, the instrument is piano which is the same, and the composer is different. This is not why it was closed as a duplicate though as I said in a comment:

> It's the same concept on a different note that's why it's a duplicate.
>   It's even the exact inverse scenario so it should be easy to see
>   what's going on.

The concept which was not addressed by your edit was the same. I rolled it back because the edit read more like a meta post then clarification for the question and adding details which is what the edit was suppose to be to get it reopened.

There have been other questions that were mainly about a topic already discussed that were closed as a duplicate, but later reopened after changing the focus of the question slightly. [This question is one recent example](https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/33706/revisions).

If there is something that the other question does not address that you want answered (i.e. besides what a Cb is as that question covers the general concept of enharmonic equivalence which is what that question is), you can either edit your question to clarify that or ask a new one.

Comment: The answer may be the same, but the question *is* different. An important consideration for a site such as this is how likely people are to find the answer they are looking for. If I search for information about Cb my search engine of choice won't match a question about B#